# If $x$ is given in degrees, are $\sin(x)$ and $\arcsin(x)$ algebric for $x$ rational?

Tags: trigonometry, algebraic-numbers

If $x$ is given in degrees, are $\sin(x)$ and $\arcsin(x)$ algebric for $x$ rational?

For the sin I think the answer is yes. We know that $\sin(1°)=\frac{\sqrt[90]{i}-\sqrt[90]{-i}}{2i}$, and we can construct $\sin(p x)$ using Chebyshev polynomials, and $\sin(x/q)$ by solving the root of a Chebyshev polynomial. Is this sound?

For arcsin I don't think this is true, but I can't find any counter-example, nor a proof.

Comment: For the arcsin question, do you mean that $x$ is a rational number and $\arcsin(x)$ is given in degrees?

Comment: If so, then I have a proof somewhere around this site that $\arctan(2)$ is not a rational multiple of $\pi$ (and therefore $\arctan(2)$ in degrees is irrational); but then, $\arcsin(3/5) = 2 \arctan(2) - 90^\circ$ must also be irrational.  I don't know of any proof that it would be transcendental, but I would be surprised if it were algebraic.

Comment: @DanielSchepler yes, the context of this question is trying to perform computer graphics using exact representations in degrees.